# Computing AABB collision

Tags: opengl, collision-detection

I'm making a game in OpenGL. The game consists on a plane flying free on a 3D world, wich has to go through some especific areas, like if it was going through windows. Right now, I'm trying to compute the collision of the plane with that mentioned "windows". I thought as a first approach, to have an swept AABB for the trajectory of the plane, and some AABBs for each window, such as if these AABB overlaps, there are potencial cases of the plane going through it.
But the problem starts when I try to calculate the AABBs, since every algorithm I know needs to know the coordinates of both objects (plane+window) in the same reference system. My program draws the world as if it is what's moving, instead of the plane, which is centered always at the origin (actually, at z=-10, so it's rendered). The real problem is how to compute the coordinates of each "window" as seen from the plane. This is the code I use to draw the scene:

```
glLoadIdentity();

//these are the rotations of the plane of the ground
glRotatef(RotHorizont, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glRotatef(-directionX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-directionY, 0, 1.0f, 0);

//and these are the movement of the plane
//(the multiplication by 0.0174532925f is to convert the angles to radians
Tx -= (float)Math.sin(directionY * 0.0174532925f) * velocity;
Tz -= (float)Math.cos(directionY * 0.0174532925f) * velocity;
Ty -= (float)Math.sin(directionX * 0.0174532925f) * velocity;

glTranslatef(-Tx, Ty, -Tz);

/*
here I draw the ground and the windows
*/
....

//and now I draw the plane
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
/* draw the plane */
```

So, how the heck do I get the coordinates of the "windows"?
Or is there some other way to compute the collision?
I really need your help, I will appreciate it so much.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an AABB by a position (3-coordinate vector) and its size (3-coordinate vector), and apply any AABB collision detection algorithm to resolve your problem.

As you pointed out, the computation has to be done in the same coordinate system. However, since you are dealing with AABBs (and not OBBs), you do not need to deal with orientation (either the AABB is computed so that the object will remain in it after rotating, or you recompute it after every object rotation). Since "AA" means "Axis-Aligned", you are normally already dealing with a common frame of reference (else it would be OBBs). Thus, the only "conversion" that could be needed is a translation.

If the center of your plane is the center of your coordinate system, your plane's AABB's position will be (0,0,0) (or (0,0,-10)). For your windows, well it depends on how you define those, but it should be fairly easy to find their centers (with OpenGL you are dealing with [products of transformation matrices](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html), find the ones taking you from the original coordinate system to the windows one). If you provide more information, we could give you some more details on how to achieve that.

**Links:**

- [Another documentation on transformations in OpenGL](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name2)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! So if I understand it correctly, I need to extract the modelmatrix for each window, and get the coordinates of the origin in that point?

Comment: I've tried it, getting the modelmatrix for a window (it's correct, since I've draw something with that matrix). But how can I extract the coordinates from that matrix? I thought that multiplying that matrix by the vector `[0; 0; 0; 1]` (representing the origin of the window), it should give me the coordinates seen from the original system, but it's not like that.
For example, with this matrix, how can I extract the coordinates seen from the plane?
`0.967    0.023    0.253    0.000
-0.112    0.933    0.342    0.000
-0.229   -0.360    0.905    0.000
15.392   89.237 -318.202    1.000`

Comment: First, I'd say that using OOP with classes handling position/orientation information would be a good idea. OpenGL would only be used to display the result. As you can see, collision detection has nothing to do with display. Can't you do that? It would probably make your life easier.

If you can't, I suppose you need to apply the invert transformation matrix to "go back" to the proper reference frame.

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand what you say, but I don't know how to do it. How can I handle position/orientation info without getting it from opengl? Did you mean re-think the entire program so I made all the calculations and then draw it with opengl? Because my program has a lot done already, and re-think all of it (regarding drawing the scene) would be too much...

Comment: Well, the objects that you draw are defined by your parameters. How do you place the windows in your scene?

Comment: They are defined by an offset in x and other in z, so for each one, starting at the origin of the ground, I translate the scene, draw it, and return to the origin:
`Iterator<Window> i = windows.iterator();

while(i.hasNext()) {
 glPushMatrix();
 Window p = i.next();
 glTranslatef(p.getCoordX(), 0.0f, p.getCoordZ());
 
 p.draw(gl);
 
 glPopMatrix();
}`

Comment: But I'm not so happy with this method, so if you think of something better, just tell me. Thank you for helping me out! ^^

Comment: What you call "origin of the ground" is the projection of your plane's position on the ground?

Comment: No, it's the center of the object "ground", the position where its draw function is called.

Comment: So you have the position of the windows in the ground's coordinate system, and you can also get the plane's position in that coordinate system, right?

Comment: The first is true, but not the second. At least, I don't know how to!

Comment: To obtain the plane's position, you just use glTranslate(0,0,-10). For the ground, you probably do something similar. By multiplying the transformation matrices in the right order, you can go from one coordinate system to another. Check that link : http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name2

Comment: Yes, if I recover the modelview matrix when I draw the ground, I can go from the plane coordinate system, to the ground coordinate system by doing glMultMatrixf. But even with that matrix, I don't know exactly how to transform the coordinates so there are in the same system.

Comment: I think I got it. If I multiply that matrix with a vector like [p.getCoordX(), 0, p.getCoordZ(), 1] I think I got th coordinates of the window in the system of the plane. Now I just have to construct the AABBs and check if they overlap. Am I correct?

Comment: If you have both the window and the plane in the same coordinate system, you can test for collision detection yes. You can also modify your collision detection function and add the transformation matrices as arguments. This is what is done with PQP for instance (http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/SSV/) : `PQP_Collide(&cres,R1,T1,&m1,R2,T2,&m2)`. Concerning the construction of the AABB, it should be computed in the object's local coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your responses, I'm so grateful! ^^ I'll return to work with that, if something is wrong, I'll comment it. Again, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If the problem is resolved, you can also accept the answer. People will still add precisions if they think they have relevant elements to add ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a really good book on the subject: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/

Alternatively this site has also a good collection of methods for calculating collisions between different types: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html